# How to use vim as a unix filter to indent source code

Tags: vim, indentation

I want to use vim as a universal source code indenter.

Here's my inital attempt at a shell function that wraps the invocation of vim to make vim reindent STDIN according to the filetype and shiftwidth parameters:

```
vim-indent () {
  local ext=$1
  local width=$2
  local file=$(mktemp --suffix=."$ext")
  cat >| "$file"
  vim -E +"set sw=$width|normal! gg=G" +'x' -- "$file" >/dev/null
  cat "$file"
}
```

## Test 1: reindent c source code with a 2 space indent

```
vim-indent c 2 << "EOF"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        char operator;
        printf("Enter an operator (+, -): ");
        scanf("%c", &operator);
        switch (operator) {
               case '+':
               case '-':
                   printf(operator);
                   break;
               default:
                   printf("Error! operator is not correct");
        }
        return 0;
}
EOF
```

**Success.** The c source was re-indented with a 2 space indent:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char operator;
  printf("Enter an operator (+, -): ");
  scanf("%c", &operator);
  switch (operator) ​{
    case '+':
    case '-':
      printf(operator);
      break;
    default:
      printf("Error! operator is not correct");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

## Test 2: reindent bash source code with a 2 space indent

```
vim-indent sh 2 << "EOF"
#!/usr/bin/bash
hello() {
        echo "Hello World"
}
if true; then
        echo "It is true"
fi
EOF
```

**Failed.** The function body was correctly indented, but not the if statement:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
hello() {
  echo "Hello World"
}
if true; then
echo "It is true"
fi
```

## Test 3: reindent html source code with a 2 space indent

```
vim-indent html 2 << "EOF"
<html>
         <body>
                 <div>
                          <p>Hello</p>
                 </div>
         </body>
</html>
EOF
```

**Failed.** No indentation at all:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I *edit* `bash` and `html` files in vim, I can reindent them fine.

Why did the above tests succeed for `c` source code, but fail for `bash` and `html` source code?

## Conclusion

I incorporated the advice from answers and created a working shell script (submitted as an answer below) that I can use as a universal source code indenter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to `.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

Depending on your html indentation preferences, you may also need to add this line to `.vimrc`:

```
let g:html_indent_inctags="html,body,head"
```

This line is needed because in some Vim versions the default html indentation file (located in `:e $VIMRUNTIME/indent/html.vim`) will not indent lines inside `<html>`, `<body>` and `<head>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

you can also define different indenting behavior thanks to `.vim/indent` folder. Then add a html.vim and and a c.vim file in this folder. You can describe all the desired behavior for each language, and you will be able to use `=` shortcut as you did.

Combine this with Sergio's previous comment and you'll get a suitable way to indent different kind of file.

Answer (score 0):

This shell script passes the 3 tests described in my question.

File: `vim-indent`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
filetype=${1:?"Usage: vim-indent FILETYPE [WIDTH]"}
shiftwidth=${2:-4} # default indent width is 4
file=$(mktemp) || { echo "Couldn't create temp file" >&2; exit 1; }
trap "rm $file" EXIT
cat > "$file"
/usr/bin/vim -u NONE -E \
  +'let g:html_indent_inctags = "p,html,body,head,tbody"' \
  +'filetype plugin indent on' \
  +"set filetype=$filetype" \
  +"syntax on" \
  +"set expandtab" \
  +"set shiftwidth=$shiftwidth|normal! gg=G" \
  +'x' -- "$file" >/dev/null
cat "$file"
```

Compared to my initial shell function, I made the following refinements:

- made it a shell script instead of a shell function
- incorporated Sergio's advice of using `filetype plugin indent on`
- I set the initialization file to NONE. I do initialization commands directly in the vim invocation, to keep the script self-contained.
- added some additional HTML tags to indent
- added a trap on EXIT to clean up the temporary file

2020-07-02: added `syntax on`; was needed for `xml` files and others.